# How to modify current bloc state like adding, updating, and deleting?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have 2 screens, the first screen is to display a list of items. The second one is a form for creating a new item. On the server side, after each `store, update, destroy` action, I returns its value back to the client as a response. The goal here is to update the state without having to make a new request over the network and showing a loading screen over and over every time the user creating a new resource and going back to the screen containing the list.

But since the `BlocBuilder` is only depends on a specific event and `state.data` is only available inside an `if (event is NameOfEvent)` statement, I couldn't modify the current state to push the new value to it.

I found that using `BlocListener` combined with `InitState` and `setState` is somehow working, but I think it makes the `state.data` is useless inside the `BlocBuilder` also making the algorithm complicated for such a small task.

Is there any simpler way to achieve this condition?

```dart
child: BlocBuilder<EducationBloc, EducationState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is EducationLoaded) {
      return ListEducationData(educations: state.data);
    }

    if (state is EducationCreated) {
      final education = state.data;
      // i want to push [education] to <ListEducationData>
    }
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list to store data and use **BlocListener** so you don't need to change ui every state changes.

```
var _listEducations = List<EducationData>();

child : BlocListener<EducationBloc,EducationState>(
     listener: (_,state){
             if (state is EducationLoaded) {
                setState(() { //update _listEducations
                   _listEducations.addAll(state.data);
                  });
                }
           },
     child : Container()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.. The new data is coming from the `EducationCreated` event. The `state.data` inside the `EducationLoaded` does not contains the new data unless the fetch request is called. I can't send the `state.data` from `EducationCreated` to `EducationLoaded` either.

Comment: why you need to send data from state EducationCrated to EducationLoaded ?
just create list variable to hold data, and use BlocListener not BlocBuilder like example above, don't forget to setState to update UI if data changes

Comment: oh sorry.. I misunderstood your answer. It works now. thanks!